# Using Nginx variables in place of CSP values

Tags: nginx

I have a fairly long Content-Security-Policy header value and I am having to place it in several `location` blocks.

Is it possible to declare a variable in the configuration that has the value of my long CSP string and then use the variable in place of the string throughout my `location` blocks?

Something like this:

```
location / {
  ...
  set_header Content-Security-Policy $csp_string;
  ...
}
...
location /somethingelse {
  ...
  set_header Content-Security-Policy $csp_string;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably not a great idea to try to use a variable for this, unless you actually want it to be different in different locations.

The best solution for things that have to be repeated is the `include`. For example I have things like this in my nginx configuration:

```
        include includes/csp_strict;
```

Where `/etc/nginx/includes/csp_strict` contains only:

```
add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'none'; img-src 'self'; script-src 'self'; style-src 'self'; frame-ancestors 'self'; base-uri 'self'; form-action 'self'";
```

Another one is `includes/csp_wordpress` which looks like:

```
add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; frame-ancestors 'self'; base-uri 'self';";
```

I can then include either of these (or many possible others) wherever they are needed.

Comment: Now why didn't I think of that?! This is a neat approach, thank you!